# Unrecognized option “csrf_token_generator” under “security.firewalls.main.form_login”

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to install the FOSUserBundle following the tutorial: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

but appears the error :

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "csrf_token_generator" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login"
```

My config.yml
           imports:
        - { resource: parameters.yml }
        - { resource: security.yml }

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled:  true
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

My security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: _security_check
            login_path: _demo_login
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

enter code here
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your security.yml file.  You have listed two CSRF token managers.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

Depending on what version of Symfony you are using you use either `csrf_token_generator` or `csrf_provider` if your version of Symfony is <2.8, not both.

You need to remove or comment one of the lines out.

---

Editing this post because I cannot comment on your new post.

> My version symfony is 2.4 : "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*"
>
> But i have these new error:
>
> ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.doctrine_registry".

This could be due to your version of Symfony being <2.6.* and conflicting with the FOSUserBundle version you are using.

For a temporary work around edit your config.yml

```
services:
    fos_user.doctrine_registry:
        alias: doctrine
        # or use this, unsure on which one for your version of Symfony
        # alias: doctrine_mongodb
```

Other fixes could be using a particular pull (older version - not recommended) in your composer.json.  This has been tested for Symfony 2.6.* and bypassing the same issue you posted.

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master##6ccff96434c0ac7fee077d1dce90966341dfd278"
```

You can read more about this particular problem:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2048

A Symfony branch exists as a temporary fix as well: 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17554